# UrlRewriting for domain

Tags: .net, url-rewriting

I'm using Intelligencia.UrlRewriter and I would creare a rule that rewrite the referring domain to my custom file, such as:

```
  <rewriter>
    <redirect url="http://www.mysiteinenglish.com" to="~/index.aspx?site=GB"/>
    <redirect url="http://www.mysiteinitalian.com" to="~/index.aspx?site=I"/>
  </rewriter>
```

How can I do that?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try IIS URL Rewrite:
http://forums.iis.net/p/1162856/1925686.aspx

It has an user interface in IIS Manager.
http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite